# What is a (finite) Baire-measure?

Tags: measure-theory

In my script I read the following:

> > Let $\Omega$ be a topological space. A sequence $\mu_n$ of finite Baire-measures is called *weakly convergent* to the finite Bare-measure $\mu$ if
> >     $$
> > \forall f\in\mathcal{C}_b(\Omega): \lim_{n\to\infty}\int f\, d\mu_n=\int f\, d\mu.
> > $$
> >     (Here $\mathcal{C}_b$ is the space of the bounded continuous functions.)

Nowhere in my script I found a definition of what a (finite) Baire-measure is. I tried to find a definition in the internet and found the following:

If $\Omega$ is a topological space then the Baire-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_0(\Omega)$ on $\Omega$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the preimages of all continuous functions $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$. And a finite Baire-measure is a measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{B}_0(\Omega)$ with $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$.

If $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$ is the Borel$-\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ (i.e. the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets of $\Omega$) then $\mathcal{B}_0(\Omega)\subseteq\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$.

If $\Omega$ is a metric space then $\mathcal{B}_0(\Omega)=\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$.

---

Is that the usual definition?

Comment: "containing the preimages of all continuous functions" There you for got to say the preimages of what. There are several equivalent ways to fill it in, so I've left that out. $\mathcal{B}_0(\Omega)$ could be characterised as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing a) $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ for all continuous $f$, b) $f^{-1}(U)$ for $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ open and $f$ continuous, c) $f^{-1}(B)$ for $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ a Borel set and $f$ continuous d),e),f)... I think that's the usual definition, although

Comment: I have the feeling I remember having read somewhere that somebody defined the Baire sets as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the compact sets. Can't swear to it, though.

Comment: Can I ask a further question? The script says: We can also say that $\mu_n$ converges to $\mu$ $*$-weakly. We defined that as follows: "Let $E$ be a Banach space and $E^*$ its dual space. Then a sequence $L_n\in E^*$ is called $*$-weakly convergent to $L\in E^*$ if $\forall f\in E: \lim_n L_n(f)=L(f)$." How does this fit here? Is here $L_n:=\mu_n$? But why is $\mu_n(f)=\int f_n\, d\mu_n$?

Comment: You identify the measure $\mu$ with the linear functional $f \mapsto \int f\,d\mu$. Thus you have a natural injection from the space of finite Baire measures into $C_b(\Omega)^\ast$ (well, you need to see that two different measures give rise to different integrals), and it's just the weak* convergence of the associated linear forms that is defined in the snippet.

Comment: And one last question hehe: "Let $\Omega$ be a tpological space. A serquence $\mu_n$ of finite measures on $\sigma(C_K(\Omega))$ is called vague convergent to the finite measure $\mu$ on $\sigma(C_K(\Omega))$ if $\forall f\in C_K(\Omega): \lim_n\int f\, d\mu_n=\int f\, d\mu$. What is $\sigma(C_K(\Omega))$? Is this the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing compact functions?

Comment: Is $C_K(\Omega)$ the space of continuous functions with compact support? I don't _know_ what $\sigma(C_K(\Omega))$ is defined as, but a natural guess is that it's the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $f^{-1}(U)$ for all $f\in C_K(\Omega)$ and $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ open.

Comment: Yes, it is the space of continious functions with compact support. I think this is right, but this kind of writing it is rather confusing to my opinion, because when I see $\sigma(C_K(\Omega))$ it looks like a $\sigma$-algebra containing functions...